# How to refresh parent without losing its ViewState?

Tags: asp.net

I use this script on the child window to refresh the parent window on clicking "Close & Refresh" :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshParent() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

However when the parent window is refreshed, the Id saved in a `ViewState` is lost and i can no longer bind my control.

Any suggestion of workarounds ?

EDIT:

Answering one of the comments: I wasn't able to use Sessions as I need to clear the session on the "Unload Event", however I discovered that the Unload event is called on postbacks (please correct me if i'm wrong) and would still lose the value.

Comment: Save id in `session`

Comment: @Bharadwaj Thank you for your suggestion, I edited my question to explain my trials with using Sessions

Comment: Are you using `JavaScript`? or `C#`?

Comment: @Bharadwaj I'm using C# in code, and using a javascript function to refresh the parent window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way viewstate works is basically saving data to the html page. So when you refresh the page the page load will recreate the page as if it was accessed the first time. Have you tried adding a query string to the parent page after you close your child page and then bind your control based on the querystring?

Note: If you have sensitive data that you dont want to store in the query string you can encrypt the value and put it in the query string. Then on the read decrypt it. One big drawback though of the querystring is that the url is now cacheable.

Example: www.yoursite.com/parentpage?childpageid=1
then in your pageload or wherver you bind the control you just check if there is a query string in the url.

Example Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RefreshParent() {
            if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location + "?childid=1";
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: That saved me a lot of effort. I made the QueryString as a parameter to the function and set it in my code. Thanks a lot